Particle filter parameter estimation
This is the graph after fitting the curve. I want estimate the parameters such at the orange (estimated curve) should lie on blue (raw data).
Particle filter for parameter estimation to get Weibull distribution
Step 1: Initialization
def initialize_particles(num_particles, Y_base_space, K_scale_space, beta_space, alpha_space):
    Y_bases = np.random.uniform(Y_base_space[0], Y_base_space[1], size=num_particles)
    K_scales = np.random.uniform(K_scale_space[0], K_scale_space[1], size=num_particles)
    betas = np.random.uniform(beta_space[0], beta_space[1], size=num_particles)
    alphas = np.random.uniform(alpha_space[0], alpha_space[1], size=num_particles)
    weights = np.ones(num_particles) / num_particles
    return Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, weights

Step 2: Prediction
def predict_particles(Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, motion_model_std):
     Y_bases = Y_bases + np.random.normal(0, motion_model_std, len(Y_bases))
     K_scales = K_scales + np.random.normal(0, motion_model_std, len(K_scales))
     betas = betas + np.random.normal(0, motion_model_std, len(betas))
     alphas = alphas + np.random.normal(0, motion_model_std, len(alphas))
     return Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas

Step 3: Update
`def update_weight(observed_data, predicted_data, motion_model_std):
    residual = observed_data - predicted_data
    likelihood = np.exp(-0.5 * np.sum(residual**2) / motion_model_std**2)
    #print(likelihood)
    # Handle potential division by zero
    if np.isclose(likelihood, 0):
       return 1e-100  # Small epsilon value
    else:
       return likelihood   

def neff(weights):
    return 1. / np.sum(np.square(weights))`

Step 4: Resampling
`def resample(Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, weights):
 indices = np.random.choice(len(Y_bases), size=len(Y_bases), p=weights)
 Y_bases = Y_bases[indices]
 K_scales = K_scales[indices]   
 betas = betas[indices]
 alphas = alphas[indices] 
 N = len(indices)
 if neff(weights) < N:
  #print("true")
  weights = np.ones(len(weights)) / len(weights)  # Reset weights
 else:
 #print("false")
 weights = weights
 return Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, weights    # Reset weights`

Main Particle Filter Algorithm for Universal Failure Rate Function Parameter Estimation
`def particle_filter_MFRF_parameter_estimation(num_particles, Y_base_space, K_scale_space, beta_space,
    alpha_space, motion_model_std, MFRF, time):

MFRF = pd.DataFrame(MFRF)  # dataframe
time = pd.DataFrame(time)  # dataframe

# Initialization
Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, weights = initialize_particles(num_particles, Y_base_space,
K_scale_space, 
                                                              beta_space, alpha_space)

# Estimate
Y_base_estimate = np.sum(Y_bases * weights)
K_scale_estimate = np.sum(K_scales * weights)
beta_estimate = np.sum(betas * weights)
alpha_estimate = np.sum(alphas * weights)

predicted_curve = Y_base_estimate + K_scale_estimate * (beta_estimate/alpha_estimate**
                                                        beta_estimate)*time**(beta_estimate-1)
residual = MFRF - predicted_curve
std = pd.Series(np.std(residual))
std = std.values[0]
print(std)
while std >= std_dev:

  # Prediction
  Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas = predict_particles(Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, 
  motion_model_std)
   
  # Update
  for i in range(num_particles):
    
      # Y + K*(beta/eta**beta)*time**(beta-1)
      predicted_MFRF = Y_bases[i] + K_scales[i] * (betas[i]/alphas[i]**betas[i])*time**(betas[i]-1)
      weights[i] = update_weight(MFRF, predicted_MFRF, motion_model_std)
    
  weights /= np.sum(weights)

  # Resampling
  Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, weights = resample(Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, weights)

Y_base_estimate = np.sum(Y_bases * weights)
K_scale_estimate = np.sum(K_scales * weights)
beta_estimate = np.sum(betas * weights)
alpha_estimate = np.sum(alphas * weights)

predicted_curve = Y_base_estimate + K_scale_estimate * (beta_estimate/alpha_estimate**
                                                        beta_estimate)*time**(beta_estimate-1)
residual = MFRF - predicted_curve
std = pd.Series(np.std(residual))
std = std.values[0]
print(std)

# Estimate the parameters as the weighted mean of particles
plt.plot(Y_bases)
plt.plot(K_scales)
plt.plot(betas)
plt.plot(alphas)

return Y_base_estimate, K_scale_estimate, beta_estimate, alpha_estimate`

Main Function Execution
`Y_base_estimate, K_scale_estimate, beta_estimate, alpha_estimate = 
 particle_filter_MFRF_parameter_estimation(
num_particles, Y_base_space, K_scale_space, beta_space, alpha_space, motion_model_std, MFRF, time)`

Plot
`predicted_MFRF = Y_base_estimate + K_scale_estimate *  
 (beta_estimate/alpha_estimate**beta_estimate)*time**(beta_estimate-1)

  print("Y_base_estimate = ",Y_base_estimate)
  print("K_scale_estimate = ", K_scale_estimate)
  print("beta_estimate = ", beta_estimate)
  print("alpha_estimate = ", alpha_estimate)
  plt.plot(time, predicted_MFRF)
  plt.plot(time, MFRF)`

I am not able to optimize the code. This is providing wrong parameter estimation. The process either stops or results in wrong parameters.
What can be done to optimize the code?
I want to set intial parameters without any bounds.
I need to estimate the parameters near the true ones.
Whatever the intial parameters, it should estimate near to true ones.
